# Responsive navigation - keep links the same height when some wrap?

Tags: css, responsive-design

Im making a menu for a responsive site. Im making the menu the full site width and each 
link 33%.

For wide screens everything is fine. The links have varying link text, so for smaller displays some links will wrap before others.

How can I make the links stay the same height (the 3rd example in my image below)? Ideally the entire area thats grey in my example would be a clickable link.

[image]

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HokAh/

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </span> 
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#">Link 2 which has very very very long text</a>
  </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  background: grey;
  padding: 10px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `display:table;` on `<ul>` and `display:table-cell;` on `<li>`

See this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pC86b/5/)**

CSS :

```
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}

li {
  display:table-cell;
  width: 33%;
  background: grey;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

---

**Update**

in order to make the whole table-cell clickable, you can add this css :

```
li {
    overflow:hidden;
}
a {
    display:block;
    margin: -10em;
    padding: 10em;
}
```

See this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/pC86b/18/)**

Comment: Bonus - if your li's aren't all the same width (or the number of them are variable), remove the width from the li's and set your child `a` tags to `display:block;` and add left and right padding and let your browser determine the optimal responsive layout - http://jsfiddle.net/pC86b/9/

Comment: Your solution looks right, however I need the entire grey area to be clickable. The way my menu is styled is that each 'tab'  (which is represented by the grey area in the fiddle example) is styled like a link. So if the entire area is not clickable this may confuse users.

Comment: This has the same issue. The link itself is clickable but the grey area surrounding it is not.

Comment: Ive found an issue for mobile devices. The whole link is highlighted when tapped, including the area normally hidden by the overflow of the link's parent element. This can be quite disorientating.