# How can I make the tap highlight show only on a parent element, not on children?

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile-webkit

Say I'm rendering this markup on iOS:

```
<a href="#" class="book">
  <span class="title">Robinson Crusoe</span>
  <span class="author">Daniel Defoe</span>
</a>
```

When the user taps inside that element, I want the little gray tap highlight to appear **only on the parent link**, not on the individual `<span>` tag that they tapped on.

So instead of this:

```
+-----------+
|###########|
|           |
+-----------+
```

I want the user to see this:

```
+-----------+
|###########|
|###########|
+-----------+
```

I experimented with code like this:

```
.book {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: initial;
}

.book * {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: none;
}
```

That code will suppress the highlight on the child spans, but it will also suppress the highlight on the parent span, so that in the end, nothing is highlighted, which isn't what I wanted.

I tried Googling but can't seem to find anything except [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456680/tap-highlight-on-parent-element-of-link-not-link-itself), which doesn't really seem related to my question.

Has anyone had experience trying to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out a way to do this (after experimenting with pseudo-classes):

```
.book {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.book:active {
  background-color: #efefef /* tap color */;
}
```

Works because iOS Safari applies `:active` styling `onTouchStart`.